# Show that the following inequality holds $\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt2>2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that the following inequality holds $$\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt2>2$$
I have just studied cubic roots and we know that if $a<b$ then $\sqrt[3]{a}<\sqrt[3]{b}$ $(a,b\in\mathbb{R}).$ Here though we also have the square root $\sqrt[2]2$. How are we supposed to approach the problem? Thank you. The approximate values are $$\sqrt[3]{2}\approx1.26;\sqrt2\approx1.41$$

So using @rtybase suggestion we have to show $\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt2>2$. We know that $\sqrt{2}>1$. Can we subtract the second inequality from the first? Is subtracting inequalities even a thing? Then we will get $\sqrt[3]2>1=\sqrt[3]{1}$ which is true.

Comment: Because $2>1$ then $\sqrt{2} >1$ ... and what can you conclude?

Comment: Since both terms are greater than $1$, you can actually draw directly to the conclusion.  But, if you want you can try this funnier inequality :-) (based on your inequality) $$\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt2>\sqrt 7$$.

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{2}>1$ and $\sqrt{2}>1$

Comment: By the way, you can also apply  Am-Gm inequality: $$\begin{align}\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt2>2\sqrt{2^{\frac 13+\frac 12}}=2^{1+\frac 56\times \frac 12}>2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have:
$$\begin{array}{l}
\sqrt[3]{2} > 2 - \sqrt{2} \iff 2 > (2 - \sqrt{2})^3\iff \\
\iff 2 > 8 - 3\cdot 2^2\cdot \sqrt{2}+3\cdot 2\cdot (\sqrt{2})^2- 2\sqrt{2}=20-14\sqrt{2}\iff \\ \iff14\sqrt{2} > 18\iff 7\sqrt{2} > 9\iff 98 > 81  \end{array}
$$,
which is true.

Comment: I took the liberty to rearrange your LaTex ..

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt 2 > x$$
$$\sqrt[3] 2 > y$$
$$\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2 > x + y > 2$$

Find some $x$ and $y$ to make that work.